# Magento development application redirecting to production URL after an update.

Tags: magento, caching, redirect

Background: I've got a dev magento site that we've been working on and had a big update that we wanted to push from a local db copy to dev. After copying the database over and pushing changes to the magento files my dev site redirects to localhost.

I've tried everything I could think of but I'm still missing something.

I've tried:

- Editing the db values for secure and unsecure sites to the dev values
- Deleting the magento var/cache contents, restarting php
- Grepping the magento directory for all instances of "localhost/[site]", only instance found was in var/cache that apparently keeps repopulating with the incorrect value after deleting
- Disabled SEO redirects and full-page caching in the core_config table and flushed cache and restarted php
- Explicitly checked the web/.htaccess file for any mention of localhost, found none
- Checked nginx vhost, no mention of localhost

I've run out of ideas, I'd appreciate any suggestions on where to look next. At the moment I'm wondering if there is an alternative cache place that is holding the old value.

Comment: When you say you disabled full page caching in core_config, did you disable it via the admin?  That should disable it in core_cache_option.  I think you can do it directly by just modifying the value in core_cache_option, but I've seen instances where that didn't work, so I'd do it in the admin.  Also, I'd try disabling cache entirely just in case, as opposed to just clearing it.  Also, I'd set a breakpoint in Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract::setRedirect() and see what's calling it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rebooting the server solved the issue.

I believe the block objects were being cached in memcached and the reboot cleared these.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to flush the other caches (that are available in the backend).

To do this pragmatically see [here](http://www.yameveo.com/development/php/flush-every-magento-cache-from-the-command-line).

Pesach

Comment: Hey, so a good old fashioned reboot solved the problem. I believe I had caching stored in memcache that was wiped clean by the reboot